# Post to blog via E-mail PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email, blogs

I'm building a simple blog platform. The person I'm building this for is blind and has asked for a solution. He's suggested that as he is already capable of using outlook it'd be good if he could just email a specific email address and it automatically inserts to the db.

Here is what I have so far (i'm using a cronjob to execute this script every 10 minutes):

```
        include('Imap.php');

    $date = date('d-M-y', strtotime('1 day ago'));
    $term = 'ALL UNDELETED SINCE "'.$date.'"';

    //ignore array of emails
    $exclude = [];

   $email    = 'email@email.com'
  $password = 'mypassword';
$host     = 'mymailhost'//your email host
$port     = '0000'//port number
$savePath = "emails";//folder to save attachments
$delete   = true;//set to true to delete email

//initialise email
$imap = new Imap($email, $password,$host,$port, 'Inbox', $savePath, $delete);

//get emails pass in the search term and exclude array
$emails = $imap->emails($term, $exclude);

foreach($emails as $email)
{
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_posts (postTitle,
postDesc,postCont,postDate) VALUES  (:postTitle, :postDesc, :postCont, 
:postDate)') ;
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':postTitle' => $email['subject'],
    ':postDesc' => substr($email['body'], 0, 200),
    ':postCont' => $email['body'],
    ':postDate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
 ));
 }
```

I also have an Imap class:

```
<?php
class Imap {
private $imap;
private $email;
private $folder;
private $host;
private $port;
private $secure;
private $connection;
private $saveFolder;
private $delete;
public function __construct($email, $password, $host, $port, $folder, $saveFolder, $delete = false)
{
    $this->email      = $email;
    $this->host       = $host;
    $this->port       = $port;
    $this->folder     = $folder;
    $this->saveFolder = $saveFolder;
    $this->delete     = $delete;
    // Connect to a remote imap server
    if ($port != '143') {
        $this->secure = 'ssl/';
    }
    $this->connection = "{{$host}:{$port}/imap/{$this->secure}novalidate-cert}$folder";
    $this->imap       = imap_open($this->connection, $email, $password);
    $accountPath = $this->saveFolder.'/'.$email;
    //create folder for email account
    if (!file_exists($accountPath)) {
        mkdir($accountPath);
    }
}
public function getFolders()
{
    if ($this->imap) {
        $folderslist = imap_list($this->imap, $this->connection, "*");
        $folders     = [];
        if (is_array($folderslist)) {
            foreach ($folderslist as $folder) {
                $folder = str_replace($this->connection, '', $folder);
                $folders[] = $folder;
            }
        }
        return $folders;
    }
}
public function decode_utf8($string)
{
    if (preg_match("@=\?.{0,}\?[Bb]\?@",$string)) {
        $string = preg_split("@=\?.{0,}\?[Bb]\?@",$string);
        while (list($key, $value) = each($string)) {
            if (preg_match("@\?=@", $value)) {
                $arrTemp    = preg_split("@\?=@", $value);
                $arrTemp[0] = base64_decode($arrTemp[0]);
                $string[$key]  = join("", $arrTemp);
            }
        }
        $string = join("", $string);
    }
    if (preg_match("@=\?.{0,}\?Q\?@", $string)) {
        $string = quoted_printable_decode($string);
        $string = preg_replace("/=\?.{0,}\?[Qq]\?/", "", $string);
        $string = preg_replace("/\?=/", "", $string);
    }
    return trim($string);
}
private function is_in_array($needle, $haystack)
{
    foreach ($needle as $stack) {
        if (in_array(strtolower($stack), $haystack)) {
             return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
public function emails($searchterms, $exclude)
{
    $search = imap_search($this->imap, $searchterms);
    if (is_array($search)) {
        /* put the newest emails on top */
        rsort($search);
        $data = [];
        foreach ($search as $msg_id) {
            $check = array();
            $header = imap_header($this->imap, $msg_id);
            $subject = $header->subject;
            $msgno   = $header->Msgno;
            $from    = $header->from;
            $date    = $header->udate;
            $to      = $header->to;
            if(array_key_exists('cc', $header)) {
                $cc  = $header->cc;
            } else {
                $cc = null;
            }
            $fromaddress = null;
            $toaddress = null;
            $ccaddress = null;
            if (is_array($from)) {
                foreach ($from as $id => $object) {
                    $fromname = $object->personal;
                    $fromaddress.= $object->mailbox . "@" . $object->host;
                    $check[] = strtolower($object->mailbox . "@" . $object->host);
                }
            }
            if (is_array($to)) {
                foreach ($to as $id => $object) {
                    $toaddress.= $object->mailbox . "@" . $object->host.' ';
                    $check[] = strtolower($object->mailbox . "@" . $object->host);
                }
            }
            if (is_array($cc)) {
                foreach ($cc as $id => $object) {
                    $ccaddress.= $object->mailbox . "@" . $object->host.' ';
                    $check[] = strtolower($object->mailbox . "@" . $object->host);
                }
            }
            $target = array(
                strtolower($this->email),
                strtolower($fromaddress),
                strtolower($toaddress),
                strtolower($ccaddress)
            );
            $path = $this->saveFolder.'/'.$this->email.'/'.$msgno.'/';
            //if not in the exclude array insert
            if($this->is_in_array($exclude, $target) == false && $this->is_in_array($exclude, $check) == false){
                $body = $this->getBody($msg_id);
                $data[] = [
                    'account'     => $this->email,
                    'folder'      => $this->folder,
                    'subject'     => $this->decode_utf8($subject),
                    'msgno'       => $msgno,
                    'emailDate'   => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date),
                    'fromName'    => $fromname,
                    'fromAddress' => $fromaddress,
                    'toAddress'   => $toaddress,
                    'ccAddress'   => $ccaddress,
                    'body'        => $this->getBody($msg_id),
                    'attachments' => $this->getAttachments($msg_id)
                ];
                if ($this->delete == true) {
                    imap_delete($this->imap, $msg_id); //mark for deletion
                    imap_expunge($this->imap); //delete all marked for deletion
                }
                //if($header->Recent == 'Y'){
                   //mark email as unread
                    //imap_clearflag_full($this->imap, $msg_id, "\\Seen");
                //}
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
public function getBody($uid) {
    $body = $this->get_part($uid, "TEXT/HTML");
    // if HTML body is empty, try getting text body
    if ($body == "") {
        $body = $this->get_part($uid, "TEXT/PLAIN");
    }
    //store email account to local variable
    $email = $this->email;
    //replace cid with full path to image
    $body = preg_replace_callback(
        '/src="cid:(.*)">/Uims',
        function($m) use($email, $uid){
            //split on @
            $parts = explode('@', $m[1]);
            //replace local path with absolute path
            $img = str_replace($parts[0], resource_url($email.'/'.$uid.'/'.$parts[0], 'Emails'), $parts[0]);
            return "src='$img'>";
       },
    $body);
    return trim(utf8_encode(quoted_printable_decode($body)));
}
public function getAttachments($uid) {
    $attachments = [];
    $info = imap_fetchstructure($this->imap, $uid);
    if (isset($info->parts)) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($info->parts as $part) {
            $path = $this->saveFolder.'/'.$this->email.'/'.$uid.'/';
            if (array_key_exists('disposition', $part)) {
                //create folder for email account
                if (!file_exists($path)) {
                    mkdir($path);
                }
                if (strtolower($part->disposition) == "inline") {
                    $this->save_inline_image($info, $i, $uid, $path);
                }
                if (strtolower($part->disposition) == "attachment") {
                    $attachments[] = $this->save_attachment($info, $i, $uid, $path);
                }
            } elseif(isset($part->parts)) {
                foreach ($part->parts as $linepart) {
                    if (array_key_exists('disposition', $part)) {
                        //create folder for email account
                        if (!file_exists($path)) {
                            mkdir($path);
                        }
                        if (strtolower($part->disposition) == "inline") {
                            $this->save_inline_image($info, $i, $uid, $path);
                        }
                        if (strtolower($part->disposition) == "attachment") {
                            $attachments[] = $this->save_attachment($info, $i, $uid, $path);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        $i++;}
    }
    return $attachments;
}
private function save_inline_image($structure, $k, $mid, $path)
{
    if (isset($structure->parts[$k]->dparameters[0])) {
        //extract file name from headers
        $fileName = strtolower($structure->parts[$k]->dparameters[0]->value);
        //extract attachment from email body
        $fileSource = base64_decode(imap_fetchbody($this->imap, $mid, $k+1, FT_PEEK));
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
          // dir doesn't exist, make it
          mkdir($path);
        }
        $file = $path.$fileName;
        //only save if file does not exist
        if(!file_exists($file) && $fileName !=''){
            file_put_contents($file, $fileSource);
        }
    }
}
private function save_attachment($structure, $k, $mid, $path)
{
    //extract file name from headers
    $fileName = strtolower($structure->parts[$k]->dparameters[0]->value);
    $file = $path.$fileName;
    $mege = imap_fetchbody($this->imap, $mid, $k+1, FT_PEEK);
    $fp   = fopen($file, 'w');
    $data = $this->getdecodevalue($mege,$structure->parts[$k]->type);
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
    return [
        'account'  => $this->email,
        'msgno'    => $mid,
        'file'     => $file,
        'fileName' => $fileName
    ];
}
private function getdecodevalue($message,$coding) {
  switch($coding) {
      case 0:
      case 1:
          //$message = imap_8bit($message);
          $message = imap_base64($message);
          break;
      case 2:
          $message = imap_binary($message);
          break;
      case 3:
      case 5:
          $message = imap_base64($message);
          break;
      case 4:
          $message = imap_qprint($message);
          break;
  }
  return $message;
}
private function get_part($uid, $mimetype, $structure = false, $partNumber = false) {
    if (!$structure) {
           $structure = imap_fetchstructure($this->imap, $uid);
    }
    if ($structure) {
        if ($mimetype == $this->get_mime_type($structure)) {
            if (!$partNumber) {
                $partNumber = 1;
            }
            $text = imap_fetchbody($this->imap, $uid, $partNumber, FT_PEEK);
            switch ($structure->encoding) {
                # 7BIT
                case 0:
                    return imap_qprint($text);
                # 8BIT
                case 1:
                    return imap_8bit($text);
                # BINARY
                case 2:
                    return imap_binary($text);
                # BASE64
                case 3:
                    return imap_base64($text);
                # QUOTED-PRINTABLE
                case 4:
                    return quoted_printable_decode($text);
                # OTHER
                case 5:
                    return $text;
                # UNKNOWN
                default:
                    return $text;
            }
       }
        // multipart
        if ($structure->type == 1) {
            foreach ($structure->parts as $index => $subStruct) {
                $prefix = "";
                if ($partNumber) {
                    $prefix = $partNumber . ".";
                }
                $data = $this->get_part($uid, $mimetype, $subStruct, $prefix . ($index + 1));
                if ($data) {
                    return $data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
private function get_mime_type($structure) {
    $primaryMimetype = array("TEXT", "MULTIPART", "MESSAGE", "APPLICATION", "AUDIO", "IMAGE", "VIDEO", "OTHER");
    if ($structure->subtype) {
       return $primaryMimetype[(int)$structure->type] . "/" . $structure->subtype;
    }
    return "TEXT/PLAIN";
}
public function numEmails()
{
    if ($this->imap) {
        return imap_num_msg($this->imap);
    }
}
public function __destruct()
{
    if ($this->imap) {
        imap_errors();
        imap_alerts();
        imap_close($this->imap);
    }
}
}
```

I also have a config.php file with my db connection stuff in. I can't get it to work

I'm a beginner and would love some help please.

UPDATE:

So I've managed to fix a few errors. I'm now getting output via the cron job. Here is the latest:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=7af70fe141699e99f62b6473588acbbf; path=/

Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
in <b>/home/mysite/public_html/blog/import.php</b> on line
<b>24</b><br />
```

I'm unable to get past the error above. I've used google and stack search but I can't find specific results.

Thanks.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: Thanks for the link and edit @JayBlanchard. Understood.